# Windows Explorer file search returns blank items

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, network-shares, search, windows-search

When searching for files on a network drive through Windows Explorer sometimes the results come back with empty blank spaces (as shown by the yellow arrows in the screenshot below) strewn throughout the results (they usually are predominantly grouped towards the top).

[image]

(the red blocks is text I've censored out)

Other computers on the network aren't having any issues searching for files on the network drive. The issue persists on this particular host even when using a different user profile.

Right-clicking on these blank results doesn't do anything. Hovering over them doesn't pop up anything either.

I have tried rebuilding the indexing database (like so https://superuser.com/a/655487/155484). That didn't help either.

Comment: I wonder if it is a permissions issue of some sort.

Comment: The other user I used on that host had full access to all files on the network drive. So I don't think that would be the issue.